# Transferring data from 1 fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

Currently trying to use a bundle to transfer information from both my IncomeFragment and ExpenseFragment to HomeFragment but I'm unsure as to how to do it. I've tried implementing doubleA's code which he provided.

This is my onAcceptClicked method from my MainActivity which takes the value of the total income/expense from the relevant fragment and transfers it to the HomeFragment:

```
public void onAcceptClicked(String fragment, String total) {

    final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (fragment == "income") {
        HomeFragment homeFrag = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle incomeBundle = new Bundle();
        incomeBundle.putString(IncomeFragment.TAG, total);
        //homeFrag.newInstance(total);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_layout, homeFrag, HomeFragment.TAG);
        ft.commit();
    }
    else if (fragment == "expense"){
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle expenseBundle = new Bundle();
        expenseBundle.putString("bundleIncome", total);
        homeFragment.setArguments(expenseBundle);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_layout, homeFragment, HomeFragment.TAG);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

I have an interface in my IncomeFragment which I use to communicate with my MainActivity so I can use the onAcceptClicked method to transfer my totals over. I plan on basically doing the same thing with my ExpenseFragment. The code below is a snippet from my IncomeFragment:

```
public interface SendIncomeData {
    public void onAcceptClicked(String fragment, String total);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_accept:
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), stringIncomeTotal, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            sendIncomeData.onAcceptClicked("income", stringIncomeTotal);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error with this line of code

```
sendIncomeData.onAcceptClicked("income", stringIncomeTotal);
```

This is the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void mos.myapplication.IncomeFragment$SendIncomeData.onAcceptClicked(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I don't know why it's saying there's a null object reference and/or how I could fix this error.

I'm guessing there's probably going to be an error displaying my totals in my HomeFragment because I haven't called the method below anywhere within my code in my MainActivity or my IncomeFragment / ExpenseFragment. The reason I haven't used it is because I wasn't sure how to get it so that the HomeFragment opens first when the application is launched.

```
    static HomeFragment newInstance(String total) 
{
    HomeFragment frag = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(TAG, total);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}
```

I don't even mind starting from scratch, as long as I can transfer totals and display them from IncomeFragment > HomeFragment and also ExpenseFragment > HomeFragment

Comment: You can learn how to use an interface to communicate between activities and fragments using this tutorial http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if bundle is null in the first place:

```
bundle = this.getArguments();

if (bundle != null)
{
    // continue with your logic
}
```

Also, all Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly. See below links for more info:

- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: Hi tried changing my code to make use of the MainActivity, not sure what to do to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people will argue that using interfaces is the best way to do that, which isn't really wrong but there are much simpler ways. **Edit:  not necessarily simpler**
-One way is to get a reference to the activity within the fragment by calling

```
this.getActivity();
```

then in your activity class you can have a method that passes the data to the other fragment since it has a reference to both fragments.

-Then there's an even better way to do it actually (though that first part is probably helpful too):

In the fragment that has the data that needs to be moved, you can get a reference to the other fragment from the FragmentManager. This assumes that you created that fragment with a string ID like so:

```
Fragment otherFragment;
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(otherFragment, "otherFrag").commit();
```

Then in the fragment with the data, you'll do:

```
FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity)getActivity();
    OtherFragment otherFragment = (OtherFragment)fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("otherFrag");
```

Then with a reference to OtherFragment (in this case), you can do something like:

```
otherFragment.dataString = "myData";
```

But you'll probably want to have a test to make sure the other fragment doesn't come back null, and if it is null you might just want to create it then and there since you already have a reference to the FragmentManager.

Edit:  I'm just going to say that I like this method more, subjectively.

Comment: You are assuming that your fragment is always there which goes against why fragments were created in the first place. Pleas do not do this. A lot of people argue that Interfaces are the way to go because it is in the Android Docs. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html Not everyone understands how to use it though. I know i had issues when i first learned this concept. If you think your way is better can you please explain why? All you say is that it is better.

Comment: @doubleA I believe that, functionally, handling fragment communication using the way I mentioned is the same as using interfaces through the activity.  The interface approach also assumes the fragment will be instantiated at the time that you call the inherited method.  You will most likely need to test if the other fragment is created no matter what you do.

Comment: + lots of interfaces = messy Activity